# Alternate interpretation of a free rotating string in 2 spatial dimensions

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions

In Zwiebach's *A First Course in String Theory*, (page 140, 2nd ed.), the case of a straight open string rotating about a fixed point is analyzed.

During the analysis, the condition of periodicity (opposed to periodicity up to a constant) is applied, since the average velocity during the period which the velocity repeats is 0 (7.55 for reference). This condition, however, is derived in a previous section assuming that the string endpoints obey free endpoint boundary conditions. Could we instead treat the circle traced by the endpoints as a radial D1 brane (similar to a holonomic constrain of 2 balls connected by a rod) thereby removing the free endpoint boundary condition? If so, how would one go about continuing the analysis as described.

*side note - this is my first time asking a question on Stack Exchange, so apologies if this question lacks proper context.